# The file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder

Tags: android, sdk

I am getting this error when I copies Android SDK folder from my friend's desktop to mine. 
I changed the path of my SDK in preferences and it told me to update my ADT which I tried to do but was unable as it gave me errors that it cannot rename my folder name.
I also tried to delete my previous SDK folder but failed.
Then also I have reinstalled the plugin in my Eclipse Indigo, no success.
My dx.jar do exist in lib folder of platform-tools.
Can some one help?

Comment: How did your friend install Android SDK ... using .exe installer or by extracting .zip package?

Comment: Well my friend got the SDK and Indigo from here friends. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the existence of an older version of `dx.jar` in the VirtualStore (a folder where windows stores user versions of system and program files).
Go to `"C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\<android-sdk path>"` and delete all the content, or just the `"\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar"` file.

i.e: if your user name is `"user32"` and your android SDK is placed in `"C:\Program Files\Java\android-sdk"`, after the update you'll probably have an obsolete version of `dx.jar` in `"C:\Users\user32\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Java\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib\"`

Comment: When I go to C:\Users\Jaime\AppData\Local\VirtualStore, I only see these two folders: 1) C:\Users\Jaime\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files 2) C:\Users\Jaime\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86).